# Tableau calculated field total number of records in title

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I'm not sure if you can quick question someone can provide me with an answer for.

I am trying to add a total number of records to the title of a sheet, however every calculated field I do returns "1" as they must be just counting one row not all the rows.

Tried:

- TOTAL(SUM([Number of Records]))
- COUNT([Number of Records])
- COUNTD([Number of Records])

I would like the title to say "Incidents Active over 7 days Total 12" (or whatever the number of records in the sheet are)
[image: Calculated Field]

Answer (score -1):

1. Put a calculated field that simply calls Size() on the detail shelf.
2. Click on that field and then Edit the Table calc to define the partitioning and addressing (aka compute using) This is the trickiest part. From your screen shot, it looks like you'd want to choose Specific Dimensions, and then set At the Level to Number. You may need to experiment or RTFM.
3. Insert Size() into your title

To understand how this works, especially the tricky step 2, read the on line help about Table Calc, and check out some of the videos and training materials on table calcs from the Tableau Conference. Last year's are available at http://tc19.tableau.com

Comment: To those who downvoted this answer, at least point out what you think is wrong. It’s hard to get more specific unless the OP publishes the workbook